# How can i write a function which will take a list item and if it contains anything but for characters will remove them and leave only words

Tags: python, regex

How can I write a regex which will take each item in a list and return only words? I have taken text and split it on spaces but this is how it looks like in a list:

```
['#include', '', 'using', 'namespace', 'std;', 'int', 'main()', '{',
'int', 'divisor,', 'dividend,', 'quotient,', 'remainder;', 'cout', '<<',
'"Enter', 'dividend:', '";', 'cin', '>>', 'dividend;', 'cout', '<<',
'"Enter', 'divisor:', '";', 'cin', '>>', 'divisor;', 'quotient', '=',
'dividend', '/', 'divisor;', 'remainder', '=', 'dividend', '%',
'divisor;', 'cout', '<<', '"Quotient', '=', '"', '<<', 'quotient', '<<',
'endl;', 'cout', '<<', '"Remainder', '=', '"', '<<', 'remainder;',
'return', '0;']
```

I need to get out only words of it

Comment: Why not use `re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b', s)` or `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)', s)` in the first place? You wouldn't have to filter the list now.

Comment: this is how it looks:
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    context = f.read()
    count = {}
    words = context.split()

Comment: Serge, perhaps, you could just use `words = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)', context)`

Comment: Does that mean you want `'"Remainder'` to become `'Remainder'`? Or do you want words that have punctuation attached to them to be dropped completely?

Comment: Wiktor, thanks! It works now!)

Comment: @SergeSoloshchenko I posted the regex based answer. Well, you may really do it the way you did, just using a `isalpha()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you are doing without a regex:

```
context = 'text #include somefile.txt more here {} abc() finally'
words = [x for x in context.split() if x.isalpha()]
print(words) # => ['text', 'more', 'here', 'finally']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/N71eTq).

Alternatively, you may grab all the "words" you need using a single regex pass with `re.findall`:

```
words = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)', context)
```

That way, you extract any 1+ ASCII letters (with `[a-zA-Z]+`) that are preceded with a whitespace or start of string AND that are followed with whitespace or end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8uxTX/2).

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `is_word()`, filter all your elements through it. Use `.isalpha()` inside your function. It's easy to strip unwanted char(s) with `.isalpha()`